# Nested dropdown select using images as links

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a nested form dropdown that requires images for the links.

In general, this is what it should look like. The selection has to display with both the category and all the images of the category. Meaning that if image selection_3 is selected under category 1 it will display the category image, all three images, and the selected one will be highlighted. If image selection 2 is selected under category 2, then it will display category 2 image, then the two images with the selected one highlighted. And when I say image, I mean there will be no text displayed, only < img >s

- Category 1 image

  - image selection 1
  - image selection 2
  - image selection 3
- Category 2 image

  - image selection 1
  - image selection 2
- Category 3 image

Please let me know if this is possible.

Thanks

C

Comment: There are a number of jQuery plug-ins that will do this for you.  One that I found as an example using a quick search: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/  (see demo under 'Templating' for an example of what you want)

Comment: I'll give it a try. It needs to allow me to list all the image selections, even the ones from the same category that are not selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found a jquery that actually works for the purposes I need. http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick

Thanks